# Loop through 2 arrays and display an image or no image

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays ads and adsimages which are populated from the database after the user perform the search. One array have ads, and another have ads images. One ad can have more than one image.

What I want is the following: I want to loop through the first array and if the addid listed in first array exist in second array to show only the first image(there may be more images), and if not, I want to show noimage.jpg file. Then I want to go to the next item in the first array and so on...

I am printing the output of the arrays like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($adds);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($addsimages);
echo "</pre>";

die();
```

This produce the following output:

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [addid] => 30
                [memberid] => 25
                [isnew] => 2
                [catid] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [addid] => 31
                [memberid] => 24
                [isnew] => 1
                [catid] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [addid] => 32
                [memberid] => 24
                [isnew] => 1
                [catid] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [addid] => 33
                [memberid] => 24
                [isnew] => 1
                [catid] => 1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [addid] => 34
                [memberid] => 24
                [isnew] => 1
                [catid] => 1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [addid] => 35
                [memberid] => 23
                [isnew] => 1
                [catid] => 1
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [addid] => 40
                [memberid] => 23
                [isnew] => 1
                [catid] => 1
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [addid] => 43
                [memberid] => 23
                [isnew] => 1
                [catid] => 1
            )

    )

        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 122
                [addid] => 30
                [filename] => 2014-02-04-2017344667375_2_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 123
                [addid] => 34
                [filename] => 2014-02-05-102031IMG_1025.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 124
                [addid] => 34
                [filename] => 2014-02-05-102221IMG_1025.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 136
                [addid] => 36
                [filename] => 2014-02-05-1039404667375_5_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 151
                [addid] => 36
                [filename] => 2014-02-05-1048444667375_a_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 152
                [addid] => 36
                [filename] => 2014-02-05-1048524667375_a_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 153
                [addid] => 36
                [filename] => 2014-02-05-1050034667375_a_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 155
                [addid] => 40
                [filename] => 2014-02-14-1813184515310_0_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 154
                [addid] => 40
                [filename] => 2014-02-14-1807104515310_0_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 162
                [addid] => 41
                [filename] => 2014-02-16-144406snowshill_lavender_harvesting_600x.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 163
                [addid] => 41
                [filename] => 2014-02-16-1444404.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 164
                [addid] => 43
                [filename] => 2014-02-22-1514464496160_0_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 166
                [addid] => 43
                [filename] => 2014-02-22-1515324496160_3_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [imageid] => 167
                [addid] => 43
                [filename] => 2014-02-22-1515554496160_3_n.jpg
                [sorder] => 0
                [visible] => 1
            )

    )
```

I was trying to do this with many loops and on the end i come out with nothing. My curreent code looks like this:

```
foreach($adds as $a) 
{
    foreach ($addsimages as $img) {
      if ($a['addid'] == $img['addid']) {
          echo $a['addid'] ."<br />";
          if($img['filename']) {
              echo $img['filename']."<br />";
              break;
          } 

      }  
   }



}

 foreach ($addsimages as $img) {
      if ($a['addid'] != $img['addid']) {
          echo $a['addid'] ."<br />";
              echo "no image <br />";
              break;
      }        
   }
```

Which outputs the following:

```
2014-02-04-2017344667375_2_n.jpg
34
2014-02-05-102031IMG_1025.jpg
40
2014-02-14-1813184515310_0_n.jpg
43
2014-02-22-1514464496160_0_n.jpg
43
no image
```

Which is obviously not what I need.

Comment: Why don't you just make a single `JOIN` query and get all the results right away instead of trying to join them in PHP?

Comment: WOW!. Loop inception. Just change the second array to be indexed by image ID `$addsimages['image_id'] = array(...image...);`. That way you won't need a very inefficient deep loop. Not to mention you can do this directly from the DB query.

Comment: As i state in other comments...search form is large, and query is already too complex. I prefer to avoid that option. Thanks for the help anyway. I appreciate that you are spending your time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put both conditions in the same foreach loop

```
foreach($adds as $a) 
{          
      $addImgIdKey = searchForId($a['addid'],$addsImages);  
      if (!is_null($addImgIdKey)) {

          echo $a['addid'] ."<br />";
          if(  isset($addsImages[$addImgIdKey]['filename']) 
              && !empty($addsImages[$addImgIdKey]['filename'])) {

              echo $addsImages[$addImgIdKey]['filename']."<br />";
          }                 
      }          
      else {
           echo $a['addid'] ."<br />";
           echo "no image <br />";                  

      }     
}

// get the id of the first match
function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
     if ($val['addid'] === $id) {
          return $key;
     }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Your code do work, but...it repeats the noimage for each record....which is not what I need. I need to print no image only once. Your code now produces the following: 'code' 0
2014-02-04-2017344667375_2_n.jpg
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
30
no image
31
no image
31
no image
31
no image
31
no image
31
....'code'

Comment: so it should `no image` only if the `addid` exists in `$addsimages` and it does not have an image filename? is that correct?

Comment: it should noimage if the addid does not exists in addsimages actually.

Comment: ok , so suppose there are 5 entries in `adds` array and 2 entries in `addsimages` array , and only 2 addids from `adds` exist in the `addsimages` array. So it should show `no image` only once even when there are 3 `addids` which are missing? am i going in the right direction?

Comment: yes.that is what i am trying to do actually. if the add has more than one image, only first one should be shown, if the adds doesn't exist in addsimages, only one no image shold be displayed.

Comment: get php error something with parenthesis i guess...let me solve that.

Comment: yeah sorry my bad .missed a `)` after `!empty($addsImages[$addImgIdKey]['filename'])`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48860/discussion-between-anurupr-and-user2417624)

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is here:

```
if($img['filename']) {
```

What are you trying to check for? empty()? isset()? Right now it's checking if $img['filename'] is true or false.

Comment: Even if i try with true, false, null...you name it..i still get the very same result.

Comment: It's actually checking if `$img['filename']` is *truthy* or *falsy*. Check [PHP type comparison tables](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 0):

If possible it would be easier (and prettier in my opinion) if your adsimages array was built like this:

```
Array (
    [<addid_1>] => Array
        (
           [<imageid_1>] => Array
               (
                  [filename] => filename_1.jpg
                  [sorder] => 0
                  [visible] => 1
               )

           [<imageid_1>] => Array
               (
                  [filename] => another_filename.jpg
                  [sorder] => 0
                  [visible] => 1
               )
        )

    [<addid_2>] => Array
        (
           [<imageid_1>] => Array
               (
                  [filename] => one_more.jpg
                  [sorder] => 0
                  [visible] => 1
               )
        )
)
```

With <addid_N> and <imageid_M> replaced by their actual id.

The code to retrieve first images would be simple:

```
foreach($ads as $ad) {
    if (isset($adsimages[ $ad['addid'] ][0]))
        echo '<img src="'.$adsimages[ $ad['addid'] ][0]['filename'].'"/>';
    else
        echo '<img src="noimage.jpg"/>';
}
```

Comment: that array is an output from a very lengthy and complcated serach, and I am not able to modify it unfortunatly. at least i will try to avoid that. there must be a solution for this...thanks for the effort anyhow...